generate constrained path using cubic or quintic polynomial
I need to write a program to generate a path using cubic/quintic polynomials.
I have written the following code to generate path for 3D space. It plots a path(using cubic polynomial) with constraints on starting point, goal point, initial velocity and goal velocity.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def cubic_trajectory(x0, xf, v0, vf, T):
    # Calculate coefficients for cubic polynomial
    a0 = x0
    a1 = v0
    a2 = (3 * (xf - x0) - (2 * v0 + vf) * T) / T ** 2
    a3 = (2 * (x0 - xf) + (v0 + vf) * T) / T ** 3
    return a0, a1, a2, a3


def generate_trajectory(a0, a1, a2, a3, T, num_points=100):
    t = np.linspace(0, T, num_points)
    x_t = a0 + a1 * t + a2 * t ** 2 + a3 * t ** 3
    return t, x_t


def plot_trajectories_3d(trajectories):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    for traj in trajectories:
        t, x_t, y_t, z_t = traj
        ax.plot(x_t, y_t, z_t,
                label=f'Trajectory from ({x_t[0]}, {y_t[0]}, {z_t[0]}) to ({x_t[-1]}, {y_t[-1]}, {z_t[-1]})')

    ax.set_xlabel('X Position')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Position')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Position')
    ax.set_title('3D Cubic Polynomial Trajectories')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


# Define multiple start and end conditions for 3D
conditions_3d = [
    {'x0': (-0.5, 0.0, 0.5), 'xf': (0.5, 0.0, 1.0), 'v0': (0, 0, 0), 'vf': (0, 10, 0), 'T': 5},
    #{'x0': (5, 5, 5), 'xf': (15, 15, 15), 'v0': (1, 1, 1), 'vf': (-1, -1, -1), 'T': 6},
    #{'x0': (-3, -3, -3), 'xf': (7, 7, 7), 'v0': (0, 0, 0), 'vf': (2, 0, 0), 'T': 4},
]

trajectories_3d = []
for cond in conditions_3d:
    a0_x, a1_x, a2_x, a3_x = cubic_trajectory(cond['x0'][0], cond['xf'][0], cond['v0'][0], cond['vf'][0], cond['T'])
    a0_y, a1_y, a2_y, a3_y = cubic_trajectory(cond['x0'][1], cond['xf'][1], cond['v0'][1], cond['vf'][1], cond['T'])
    a0_z, a1_z, a2_z, a3_z = cubic_trajectory(cond['x0'][2], cond['xf'][2], cond['v0'][2], cond['vf'][2], cond['T'])

    t, x_t = generate_trajectory(a0_x, a1_x, a2_x, a3_x, cond['T'])
    _, y_t = generate_trajectory(a0_y, a1_y, a2_y, a3_y, cond['T'])
    _, z_t = generate_trajectory(a0_z, a1_z, a2_z, a3_z, cond['T'])

    trajectories_3d.append((t, x_t, y_t, z_t))

plot_trajectories_3d(trajectories_3d)


Now I need to extend this code such that the generated path is within a particular region. For example in the blue region in the image below.
QUESTION:

How can I add constraints to cubic or quintic polynomial such that the generated line is within a region. For example in the blue colored region below:


For example if I generate a line from (3,4) to (8,5), the output line should look like the red line in the image below(means not passing through the white portion):

Thanks

Nothing in the question is about programming, there is not a single line of code, try math stack exchange instead, stack overflow is only for programming questions.

@AhmedAEK Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the code for what i have done till now. I usually avoid adding code initially so as to get different view of people about the problem. If I add the code initially then the answers would revolve around the method I currently have used and I might miss out on other techniques people have in mind.

Your question is not getting views, you need to tag a programming language with a specific programming question, the question is too broad, even if it got views it is unlikely to be answered as is, i think you should head over to mathexchange instead. My opinion in your problem is to iteratively subdivide the line into a number of segments and optimize the control points until all points lie within your constraint using some penalty method.

I asked the question on MathStackExchange but didnt got any solution.

Good job improving the question!

@Reinderien Yes, the start and end points and all the intermediate points of the generated path should exist within the blue region. It does not matters where the path goes before the start point and after the end point.

@Reinderien The image that i have added to this post are 2d but actually i want then in 3d(like the path in the code). I was not able to draw a 3D drawing. Its 3D image would not make much sense in 2D.  Just for understanding assume that there are 2 SPHERES one inside the other. All points of the generated path should be within volume of big sphere MINUS(-) volume of small sphere.

What are v, T? Why are they defined alongside x? It seems like your start and endpoints are fully defined by x, and v and T should be left to optimisation.

@Reinderienwe T is the independent variable and x, y, and z are dependent variables.  T stands for time. v is the velocity that i would like to have at the start and end of the path.  we are calculating coefficients for each axis separately (a0_x, a1_x, a2_x, a3_x for x, a0_y, a1_y, a2_y, a3_y for y and a0_z, a1_z, a2_z, a3_z for z), and then trajectory for each axis separately (x_t for x, y_t for y and z_t for z). Later we are combining these trajectories to get a 3D trajectory. Let me know if anything is unclear.

If T is an independent variable how could it meaningfully take a single value of 5? Is that the total time?

@Reinderien yes it is the total time it should take to reach from start to goal.

Your cubic_trajectory is a fixed method, given endpoint velocities and positions, to generate a polynomial for one dimension. Is that just to generate an initial polynomial? An optimizer needs to change something - what can it change?

@Reinderien Yes, we will call cubic_trajectory 3 times(one for x, then y, next z) then we would combine these to get a 3d plot. There were 2 constrains that were needed to be applied, first was to have a specific velocity at start and end. The other one was to have trajectory within an area(like the area between the 2 spheres). I am able to apply constraint on velocity but have no idea how to apply constraint on having trajectory points within a specific area.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Reinderien For your question about an optimizer, I think we could only change those 4 coefficients in such a way that both the constraints are satisfied(one for velocity and the other for the specific area).

It's definitely possible to generate a constrained path, but this may not be realizable as a robotic arm path unless you also add constraints on acceleration.
You also need to choose an objective beyond just "feasible path". For instance, after a first pass that establishes a feasible path, you can do a second pass that hardens the radius costs to constraints and represents total energy as a cost. Total energy can be inferred from integral of the absolute acceleration, which in turn can be calculated from a second gradient call.
import dataclasses
import functools
import typing

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Path3DCollection


class Path(typing.NamedTuple):
    space: 'PathSpace'
    polys: tuple[Polynomial, ...]
    position: np.ndarray

    @classmethod
    def from_array(cls, space: 'PathSpace', params: np.ndarray) -> 'typing.Self':
        by_dim = params.reshape((len(space.p0), -1))
        polys = tuple(
            Polynomial(symbol='t', coef=coef) for coef in by_dim
        )
        return cls(
            space=space, polys=polys,
            position=np.array([
                poly(space.t) for poly in polys
            ]),
        )

    def velocity(self) -> np.ndarray:
        # Numerical, less-accurate alternative:
        # return np.gradient(self.position, self.space.dt, axis=1)

        series = [
            poly.deriv()(self.space.t)
            for poly in self.polys
        ]
        return np.array(series)

    def position_endpoints(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.position[:, [0, -1]]

    def velocity_endpoints(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self.velocity()[:, [0, -1]]

    def endpoints(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.concatenate((self.position_endpoints().T, self.velocity_endpoints().T))

    def lower_radii(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.linalg.norm(self.position.T - self.space.inner_sphere_centre, axis=1)

    def upper_radii(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.linalg.norm(self.position.T - self.space.outer_sphere_centre, axis=1)

    def energy(self) -> float:
        accel_polys = [
            poly.deriv(2)
            for poly in self.polys
        ]
        abs_accel = np.abs([
            poly(self.space.t)
            for poly in accel_polys
        ])
        return abs_accel.sum(axis=1)

    def dump(self) -> None:
        print('Polynomials:')
        for sym, poly in zip('xyz', self.polys):
            print('    ', sym, '=', poly)
        print('Position endpoints approximating', self.space.p0, self.space.p1)
        print(self.position_endpoints().round(6))
        print('Velocity endpoints approximating', self.space.v0, self.space.v1)
        print(self.velocity_endpoints().round(6))
        print(
            f'Worst-case radii: '
            f'{self.space.inner_sphere_radius} <= {self.lower_radii().min():.2f}, '
            f'{self.upper_radii().max():.2f} <= {self.space.outer_sphere_radius}'
        )

    def plot(self, ax: 'Axes3D', title: str) -> None:
        ax.plot3D(*self.position, label=title)


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class PathSpace:
    p0: tuple[float, float, float]  # Start position
    p1: tuple[float, float, float]  # End position
    v0: tuple[float, float, float]  # Start velocity
    v1: tuple[float, float, float]  # End velocity
    inner_sphere_centre: tuple[float, float, float]  # Lower bound centroid
    outer_sphere_centre: tuple[float, float, float]  # Upper bound centroid
    inner_sphere_radius: float  # Lower bound radius
    outer_sphere_radius: float  # Upper bound radius
    duration: float  # Total time
    resolution: int = 50  # Number of points in the generated path
    order: int = 5  # of the path polynomials

    @functools.cached_property
    def t(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.linspace(start=0, stop=self.duration, num=self.resolution + 1)

    @functools.cached_property
    def dt(self) -> float:
        return self.duration/self.resolution

    def initial_polys(self) -> np.ndarray:
        coefs = np.zeros((len(self.p0), 1 + self.order))
        coefs[:, 0] = self.p0
        coefs[:, 1] = (np.array(self.p1) - self.p0)/self.duration
        return coefs

    def solve(self) -> tuple[Path, Path]:
        flat_endpoints = np.concatenate((self.p0, self.p1, self.v0, self.v1))
        endpoint_constraint = scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint(
            fun=self.endpoints, lb=flat_endpoints, ub=flat_endpoints,
        )

        feasible_result = scipy.optimize.minimize(
            fun=self.lstsq_error,
            x0=self.initial_polys().ravel(),
            constraints=endpoint_constraint,
        )
        if not feasible_result.success:
            raise ValueError(feasible_result.message)

        energy_result = scipy.optimize.minimize(
            fun=self.energy_cost,
            x0=feasible_result.x,
            constraints=(
                endpoint_constraint,
                scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint(
                    fun=self.lower_radii, lb=self.inner_sphere_radius, ub=float('inf'),
                ),
                scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint(
                    fun=self.upper_radii, lb=-float('inf'), ub=self.outer_sphere_radius,
                ),
            ),
        )

        return (
            Path.from_array(space=self, params=feasible_result.x),
            Path.from_array(space=self, params=energy_result.x),
        )

    def lstsq_error(self, params: np.ndarray) -> float:
        path = Path.from_array(space=self, params=params)
        lower_errors = (
            self.inner_sphere_radius - path.lower_radii()
        ).clip(min=0)
        upper_errors = (
            path.upper_radii() - self.outer_sphere_radius
        ).clip(min=0)
        errors = np.concatenate((lower_errors, upper_errors))

        # convert error vector to least-squares scalar
        return errors.dot(errors)

    def endpoints(self, params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        path = Path.from_array(space=self, params=params)
        return path.endpoints().ravel()

    def energy_cost(self, params: np.ndarray) -> float:
        path = Path.from_array(space=self, params=params)
        energy = path.energy()
        return energy.sum()

    def lower_radii(self, params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return Path.from_array(space=self, params=params).lower_radii()

    def upper_radii(self, params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return Path.from_array(space=self, params=params).upper_radii()

    def plot(self, ax: 'Axes3D') -> None:
        ax.scatter3D(*self.p0, label='p0')
        ax.scatter3D(*self.p1, label='p1')

        sphere(
            ax=ax, u_count=20j, j_count=10j,  label='inner bound',
            radius=self.inner_sphere_radius, centre=self.inner_sphere_centre,
        )
        sphere(
            ax=ax, u_count=40j, j_count=20j, label='outer bound',
            radius=self.outer_sphere_radius, centre=self.outer_sphere_centre, alpha=0.3,
        )

        ax.set_xlabel('x')
        ax.set_ylabel('y')
        ax.set_zlabel('z')


def sphere(
    ax: 'Axes3D',
    u_count: complex,
    j_count: complex,
    radius: float,
    centre: tuple[float, float, float],
    label: str,
    alpha: float = 1,
) -> 'Path3DCollection':
    u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:u_count, 0:np.pi:j_count]
    x = np.cos(u) * np.sin(v)
    y = np.sin(u) * np.sin(v)
    z = np.cos(v)
    xi = radius*x + centre[0]
    yi = radius*y + centre[1]
    zi = radius*z + centre[2]
    return ax.scatter3D(xi, yi, zi, s=1, alpha=alpha, label=label)


def main() -> None:
    # These do NOT reflect the reality of a 1.2m four-link robotic arm.
    all_spaces = (
        PathSpace(
            # v1=(0, 10, 0) is not practical
            p0=(-0.5, 0., 0.5), v0=(0., 0., 0.),
            p1=( 0.5, 0., 1. ), v1=(0., 5., 0.),
            duration=5.,
            inner_sphere_centre=(0.1, -0.1, 0.2), inner_sphere_radius=0.6,
            outer_sphere_centre=(0. ,  0. , 1. ), outer_sphere_radius=1. ,
        ),
        PathSpace(
            p0=( 5.,  5.,  5.), v0=( 1.,  1.,  1.),
            p1=(15., 15., 15.), v1=(-1., -1., -1.),
            duration=6.,
            inner_sphere_centre=(0.1, -0.1, 0.2), inner_sphere_radius= 7.,
            outer_sphere_centre=(0. ,  0. , 1. ), outer_sphere_radius=28.,
        ),
        PathSpace(
            p0=(-3., -3., -3.), v0=(0., 0., 0.),
            p1=( 7.,  7.,  7.), v1=(2., 0., 0.),
            duration=4.,
            inner_sphere_centre=(0.1, -0.1, 0.2), inner_sphere_radius= 3.5,
            outer_sphere_centre=(0. ,  0. , 1. ), outer_sphere_radius=15. ,
        ),
    )

    for space in all_spaces:
        feasible_path, energy_path = space.solve()
        print('Feasible path:')
        feasible_path.dump()
        print('Energy-efficient path:')
        energy_path.dump()
        print()

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
        space.plot(ax)
        feasible_path.plot(ax, title='Feasible')
        energy_path.plot(ax, title='Efficient')
        ax.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Feasible path:
Polynomials:
     x = -0.5 + (1.62772267e-23) t + 0.3503209 t**2 - 0.28280783 t**3 +
0.07908462 t**4 - 0.00698718 t**5
     y = 0.0 + (1.20507891e-23) t - 2.63144819 t**2 + 2.45195622 t**3 -
0.7050087 t**4 + 0.06397508 t**5
     z = 0.5 + (1.6085689e-18) t + 0.16248468 t**2 - 0.0582134 t**3 +
0.0077872 t**4 - 0.00036878 t**5
Position endpoints approximating (-0.5, 0.0, 0.5) (0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
[[-0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.  -0. ]
 [ 0.5  1. ]]
Velocity endpoints approximating (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 5.0, 0.0)
[[ 0. -0.]
 [ 0.  5.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
Worst-case radii: 0.6 <= 0.66, 1.00 <= 1.0
Energy-efficient path:
Polynomials:
     x = -0.5 + (5.87576423e-25) t + 0.39036819 t**2 - 0.29438286 t**3 +
0.07890896 t**4 - 0.00680942 t**5
     y = 0.0 - (1.23326358e-25) t - 2.69354583 t**2 + 2.50058162 t**3 -
0.71700715 t**4 + 0.06492653 t**5
     z = 0.5 + (4.02918561e-22) t + 0.17961151 t**2 - 0.07440046 t**3 +
0.0122068 t**4 - 0.00074223 t**5
Position endpoints approximating (-0.5, 0.0, 0.5) (0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
[[-0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.  -0. ]
 [ 0.5  1. ]]
Velocity endpoints approximating (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 5.0, 0.0)
[[ 0.  0.]
 [-0.  5.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
Worst-case radii: 0.6 <= 0.66, 1.00 <= 1.0

Feasible path:
Polynomials:
     x = 5.0 + 1.0 t + 0.00186909 t**2 + 0.0074451 t**3 + 0.0220539 t**4 -
0.00337671 t**5
     y = 5.0 + 1.0 t + 0.00186909 t**2 + 0.0074451 t**3 + 0.0220539 t**4 -
0.00337671 t**5
     z = 5.0 + 1.0 t + 0.00186909 t**2 + 0.0074451 t**3 + 0.0220539 t**4 -
0.00337671 t**5
Position endpoints approximating (5.0, 5.0, 5.0) (15.0, 15.0, 15.0)
[[ 5. 15.]
 [ 5. 15.]
 [ 5. 15.]]
Velocity endpoints approximating (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
[[ 1. -1.]
 [ 1. -1.]
 [ 1. -1.]]
Worst-case radii: 7.0 <= 8.55, 25.61 <= 28.0
Energy-efficient path:
Polynomials:
     x = 5.0 + 1.0 t + 0.89433314 t**2 - 0.36750624 t**3 + 0.07266568 t**4 -
0.00552847 t**5
     y = 5.0 + 1.0 t + 0.89429503 t**2 - 0.36746431 t**3 + 0.07265488 t**4 -
0.00552766 t**5
     z = 5.0 + 1.0 t + 0.89426736 t**2 - 0.3674362 t**3 + 0.07264781 t**4 -
0.00552713 t**5
Position endpoints approximating (5.0, 5.0, 5.0) (15.0, 15.0, 15.0)
[[ 5. 15.]
 [ 5. 15.]
 [ 5. 15.]]
Velocity endpoints approximating (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
[[ 1. -1.]
 [ 1. -1.]
 [ 1. -1.]]
Worst-case radii: 7.0 <= 8.55, 25.65 <= 28.0

Feasible path:
Polynomials:
     x = -3.0 + (4.4408921e-16) t + 0.53461923 t**2 + 1.44358752 t**3 -
0.65797237 t**4 + 0.07568107 t**5
     y = -3.0 + (4.4408921e-16) t + 3.96838631 t**2 + 2.24463206 t**3 -
1.67107596 t**4 + 0.22523908 t**5
     z = -3.0 + 0.0 t - 1.07776477 t**2 + 1.07596496 t**3 - 0.14058908 t**4 -
0.00549484 t**5
Position endpoints approximating (-3.0, -3.0, -3.0) (7.0, 7.0, 7.0)
[[-3.  7.]
 [-3.  7.]
 [-3.  7.]]
Velocity endpoints approximating (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (2.0, 0.0, 0.0)
[[0. 2.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
Worst-case radii: 3.5 <= 4.05, 14.62 <= 15.0
Energy-efficient path:
Polynomials:
     x = -3.0 - (5.55905085e-22) t + 2.69660108 t**2 - 1.23659809 t**3 +
0.27674884 t**4 - 0.0242686 t**5
     y = -3.0 + (7.33606319e-22) t + 5.00901898 t**2 - 2.89516277 t**3 +
0.70370283 t**4 - 0.06347833 t**5
     z = -3.0 - (2.98328286e-20) t - 1.40354787 t**2 + 1.2119847 t**3 -
0.14751462 t**4 - 0.00717433 t**5
Position endpoints approximating (-3.0, -3.0, -3.0) (7.0, 7.0, 7.0)
[[-3.  7.]
 [-3.  7.]
 [-3.  7.]]
Velocity endpoints approximating (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) (2.0, 0.0, 0.0)
[[-0.  2.]
 [ 0. -0.]
 [-0. -0.]]
Worst-case radii: 3.5 <= 3.50, 11.58 <= 15.0



The "Feasible" path and "Efficient" path both follows the velocity constraint? Efficient path is an optimized version to save energy?  The code works good just a bit slow, maybe due to plotting and the second pass for optimization. Programming it in c++ might help. Will look into it on my end. Thanks.

Yes and yes. Try removing the plotting to evaluate speed.
